# How to log JSON object in java spring boot?

Tags: java, spring, logging

I need to log message in json formate. Not like this

```
{
"level":"INFO",
"message": "log message"
}
```

I want to log json object which can be

```
{
"level":"INFO",
"json_att1":"value1",
"json_att2": "value2"
}
```

There is no message field in my wish. I just want to use the pseudo code 
 like this log.info(jsonObj)

**The essential need is I want to add custom field in the json log**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Logging to JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8904907/logging-to-json)

Comment: As I know, Python can do this use a package logstash_formatter

Comment: Have u tried JSON Layout of Log4j https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/layouts.html

Answer (score -2):

You can use [link](https://github.com/stleary/JSON-java) library.
Example:

```
    String str = new JSONObject()
                .put("level","debug")
                .put("prop1", "val1").toString();

    logger.debug(str);
```